# static files vs streaming node.js

Tags: node.js, express, fs, multer

what's better for sending large files from the server like 'audio' files, static files of streams?
i'm implementing an audio player api using node.js and express.js but i'm looking for the better performance.

i can send audio using express like this:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'uploads')));
```

Or using fs streams like:

```
export async function streamAudio(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        const filePath: string = req.params.fileName;

        const actualPath = path.join(__dirname, "/../../../", filePath);
        console.log(actualPath);

        const state = fs.statSync(actualPath);
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
            "Content-Length": state.size,
        });

        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(actualPath);

        readStream.pipe(res);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

I have another problem, how to make the audio un able to be downloaded? So I can make a download end-point option for tracking downloads.

Comment: At a guess I'd probably say a stream.

Comment: i'd like to use it too, but what is the deference between it and express static, and the most important question, does express implemented to act like node streams??

Comment: Express static is more of less for page scripts (js), styling information (css, scss, less, etc) and images. Anything that doesn't change. To answer your question on if express accepts streams, I don't think so however I believe [socket.io](https://npmjs.com/package/socket.io) does.